# How does electron excitation work for the Bohr model with non hydrogen atoms?

Tags: photons, electrons, atomic-physics, atomic-excitation

I've seen a lot of explanations of electron excitation by photons in the Bohr model but they all use a hydrogen atom which only has one electron. 
How does the excitation work for atoms with more electrons and thus more energy levels?

It should follow the same rules as the hydrogen atom's electron if the excited electron is in the last energy level of the atom.

But what if a photon with the right energy hits an electron in one of the lower energy levels, will it jump to a higher energy despite there already being electrons of higher energy in the atom? What if the energy level it should jump to is full?

Comment: Basically, the math (and the orbitals) get messy fast. You get level-splitting, which is essentially a bunch of levels of orbitals (which involve "sharing" the electron across nuclei) with near-equal energies.  Pauli still holds: you only get one electron in each specific level, to within spin.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft doesn't Pauli principle only make sense in full quantum theory, but not in Bohr model? We can't require the wavefunctions to be antisymmetric because there're no wavefunctions in Bohr model!

Comment: @Ruslan You use the ad-hoc "identical particles can't have all their quantum numbers the same" version that the anti-symmerization explained.

Comment: Alright, from what I gather, with the Pauli exclusion principle the electron will not jump to an energy level that's already full. But if we have a carbon atom, if one of the 2 inner electrons, on the first energy level gets hit with a photon that will make it jump to the second energy level, where will it go? It has to have the opposite spin of the other 4 electrons so the quantum numbers aren't the same.

Comment: You're not getting it.  Please take the time to read some introductory text on nuclear models and Pauli principle.